# Hardware decoding on 18.04 with nvidia

Tags: hardware-acceleration, hevc

I can not get hardware decoding for HEVC 10 bit files and VP9 (YouTube) through web browsers to work. Tried a bunch of online "solutions" with no luck.

I have a nVidia GTX 1050 (2GB), running Kubuntu 18.04 with the nVidia driver 430.29.

Is nVidia just a lost cause? Is AMD a better bet?

Comment: Install and run `vdpauinfo` to see if You have properly installed Nvidia drivers for hardware decoding. Then in Chrome (or any other browser) make sure You have enabled the `Use hardware acceleration when available` option in settings. Then in `chrome://gpu/` make sure You have `Hardware Acceleration` enabled. If not enable `chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist` flag and check again.

Comment: «Hardware Acceleration» and «HTML5 Video GPU decoding» are different things. Chrome (not Chromium) can not use GPU decoding on Linux. It's doesn’t support by code. Same thing for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

For hardware decoding HEVC 10 bit video you can use mpv player with cuda.
Just install mpv player `sudo apt install mpv` and create configuration file in which you'll put one line, using this command `echo "hwdec=cuda"  > ~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf`

For browsers there are not any good working and stable solutions (same thing for AMD).
You need some sort of this: Chromium-VAAPI + VAAPI over VDPAU (vdpau-va-driver package).
And only fresh versions, because VP9 decoding has been added to VDPAU in July 2019

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/vdpau/2019-July/000442.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried the cuda thing and I got this:

*Playing: /home/user/Downloads/jellyfish-140-mbps-4k-uhd-hevc-10bit.mkv
 (+) Video --vid=1 (*) (hevc 3840x2160 29.970fps)
 (+) Audio --aid=1 (*) (truehd 6ch 48000Hz)
Requested hardware decoder not compiled.
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 5.1(side) 6ch s32
VO: [gpu] 3840x2160 yuv420p10
AV: 00:00:00 / 00:00:30 (1%) A-V:  0.429 Dropped: 7*

Audio/Video desynchronisation detected! Possible reasons include too slow
hardware, temporary CPU spikes, broken drivers, and broken files. Audio
position will not match to the video (see A-V status field).

AV: 00:00:30 / 00:00:30 (99%) A-V:  0.000 Dropped: 539

Exiting... (End of file)

But then I tried recompiling mpv following this guide:
https://tome.one/playing-10bit-hevc-videos-on-linux-with-nvidia-and-mpv.html
And that worked, I did get a bunch of errors in the terminal, but it worked.

However I decided to returned my 1050 purchase because 2GB just didn't cut it.
An AMD RX570 is on the way and hopefully things will just work on that.
Didn't have time to try all you guys' chrome solutions, but thanks for your answers, might help me when I get the AMD.

Answer (score 0):

Rx 570 doesnot support vp9 decoding. If u want gpu for hardware acceleration i would suggest go for a gtx 1650. 
Amd supports hardware based decoding only on vega based gpu 
Eg :  rx 5700 or upcoming rx5500 or igpu of ryzen processor s

I would suggest a minimum of 6gb gtx 1660 of you want vp9 and HEVC 
Or , if u can wait a couple of months for a 4gb rx5500 which has already been announced .

Ps: gtx 1650 doesnot support decoding HVEC only vp9 . From gtx 1660 onwards all types of decoding is supported.